# Updating divs with jQuery append/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, append

I get data from an external JSON file that I loop through with jQuery each and then output to HTML.

Since the JSON data updates quite often I also want to update the HTML in these divs every minute or so. I've been reading up on this and understand that the easiest way to accomplish this is to use html() instead of append(). This does not work for me since it only outputs the last div in my loop.

With append it outputs all of my divs but, of course, they keep stacking when the script runs again. I've tried working around this by clearing the div I'm appending to before I do anything else, but this results in a horrible flickering.

Is there any way to solve this?

Here is the code with my empty() workaround.

```
<div class="content lounge-content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function repeat(){
    $('.lounge-content').empty();
    $.getJSON('https://api.import.io/store/data/dde648b1-fae1-49c1-a4b8-a084e34119fd/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com%2F&_user=213e76f7-c31e-4e56-bd2f-b7463aa8df8e&_apikey=213e76f7c31e4e56bd2fb7463aa8df8e4d47f273f4f49901a03092c93455f74df3cb1f165c675c467e69380c0f2fcac66cbbe5db7e92a0764d915fc8ab62f46a64e1298b3514ce2c2d6fd43f211f91a7', function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
            $(".lounge-content").append('<a href="'+val.MATCH_LINK+'" target="_blank"><div class="lounge-item"><p>'+val.whenm_text+'</p><h3>'+val.team1+'</h3><span>'+val.team1_percent+'</span><p> - </p><span>'+val.team2_percent+' </span><h3>'+val.team2+'</h3><p>'+val.best_of+', '+val.EVENTM_TEXT+'</p></div></a><hr>');
        })
    });
}

setInterval(repeat, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: You could try to animate if the flickering is not solved with the solutions below.

Comment: Yes, @Gothdo, I figured someone would comment on that. I just want to use a much shorter interval when testing so that I can see if the flicker is gone without having to wait a minute between each interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct one "long" string of your entire HTML and set that as the html property:

```
function repeat() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.import.io/store/...', function(data) {
        var longHTML = '';
        $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
            longHTML += '<a href="'+val.MATCH_LINK+'" target="_blank"><div class="lounge-item"><p>'+val.whenm_text+'...';
        });
        $(".lounge-content").html(longHTML);
    });
}

setInterval(repeat, 5000);
```

As an added "bonus", you'd get improved performance since manipulating strings is much faster than manipulating DOM.

Comment: Op already gives the `append()` a big html string. How is this different?

Comment: "long" & "big" are relative adjectives. A string is (or isn't) long only in comparison to another string. In this case it is *longer* than the one used in the question. Having said all that, the length of the string is not relevant to the answer. The fact that a single call to set the entire html is used ***is*** the important thing here, and in order to do that one first has to concatenate multiple strings to a single, longer string

Comment: No my point was that it you are both you and OP are using strings not that one is longer than the other :)

Comment: @Mikey - sooo.. I don't understand your comment. Do you have anything important to say about my answer? Do you find it hard to understand? Do you think it's somehow wrong?

Comment: Nah, mate I do understand what you are doing and there was no critque whatsoever in my comment. You obviously did not get the message. I just made a comment on that the append method also takes a string as an argument and it just looked like you were focussing on the string part, but it's the concatonation that makes the difference. I know I don't need to explain it to you, but I just wanted to make it clear to OP...

Answer (score 1):

You should empty the html parts after fetching the json data

```
function repeat(){
  $.getJSON('url', function(data) {
      $('.lounge-content').empty();
      $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
        $(".lounge-content").append('thing');
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes it will help with the flickering, but Amit's answer is even better.